# Is it possible ajax upload progress bar in IE without flash?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, progress-bar

So all solutions I have found uses flash for uploading files, or don't show progress bar in IE (7-8).

There is no event "progress" in MSDN documentation for XMLHTTPRequest. Is it possible at all?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you could use a PHP extension such as [uploadprogress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress/1.0.1) which I assume would be browser-independent (never tested, but I don't see why the browser would pose a problem). Or, you can set [session.upload_progress.enabled](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php) in php.ini (again, never tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create simple HTML Progress bar without using Flash. Infact you can see live examples

in many sites. In Java platform, you may use Apache's common.fileupload library where you get

a progress listener interface, which you can call using AJAX. AJAX will get the amount of

bytes in total and uploaded. You can use javascript to update the progress bar easily.

The complete code list can be found on Apache's fileupload's homepage.

For PHP, you need to have some third parties installed.